# WebGL How to prevent increase rotation speed?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm writing simple script in WebGL, but I have on problem that I can't handle. 
I want to display something in 3D in canvas and rotate it after user choose rotation axis and click 'Uruchom' button.

But every time button is clicked rotation speed is increasing. 
I want it to be constant, but don't know how. 
Thanks in advance.

```js
var gl_canvas;
var gl_ctx;

var _triangleVertexBuffer;
var _triangleFacesBuffer;
var _position;
var _color;
var _PosMatrix;
var _MovMatrix;
var _ViewMatrix;
var _matrixProjection;
var _matrixMovement;
var _matrixView;

var rotationSpeed = 0.001;
var zoomRatio = -6;

var X, Y, Z;

function runWebGL () {
  getRotation();
  gl_canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
  gl_ctx = gl_getContext(gl_canvas);
  gl_initShaders();
  gl_initBuffers();
  gl_setMatrix();
  gl_draw();
}

function getRotation() {
  X = document.getElementById('rotateX').checked;
  Y = document.getElementById('rotateY').checked;
  Z = document.getElementById('rotateZ').checked;
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_getContext (canvas) {
  try {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
    ctx.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
    ctx.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (!ctx) {
    document.write('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.')
  }
  return ctx;
}

// ==================================================================== //

// Declare the shaders. They are pieces of code compiled by WebGL and
// executed on the graphics device. They are written in GLSL.
function gl_initShaders () {
  // position of the point - 0. is Z and 1. is W
  // PosMatrix is uniform variable - its value is constant while rendering an object
  // MovMatrix is the movement matrix of the triangle
  // gl_position -> we move position with MovMatrix before projecting it
  var vertexShader = "\n\
attribute vec3 position;\n\
uniform mat4 PosMatrix;\n\
uniform mat4 MovMatrix;\n\
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix; \n\
attribute vec3 color;\n\
varying vec3 vColor;\n\
void main(void) {\n\
gl_Position = PosMatrix * ViewMatrix * MovMatrix * vec4(position, 1.);\n\
vColor = color;\n\
}";

  // set black color
  var fragmentShader = "\n\
precision mediump float;\n\
varying vec3 vColor;\n\
void main(void) {\n\
gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);\n\
}";

  // this function is used to compile a shader
  var getShader = function(source, type, typeString) {
    var shader = gl_ctx.createShader(type);
    gl_ctx.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl_ctx.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl_ctx.getShaderParameter(shader, gl_ctx.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      alert('error in' + typeString);
      return false;
    }
    return shader;
  };

  // Compile the vertex and fragment shaders
  var shader_vertex = getShader(vertexShader, gl_ctx.VERTEX_SHADER, "VERTEX");
  var shader_fragment = getShader(fragmentShader, gl_ctx.FRAGMENT_SHADER, "FRAGMENT");


  // Create the Shader program.
  // Shader program is a combination of a vertex and fragment shaders.
  var SHADER_PROGRAM = gl_ctx.createProgram();
  gl_ctx.attachShader(SHADER_PROGRAM, shader_vertex);
  gl_ctx.attachShader(SHADER_PROGRAM, shader_fragment);


  // Linking of the shader program to the WebGL context - gl_ctx,
  // in order to match the shader variables to javascript variables
  gl_ctx.linkProgram(SHADER_PROGRAM);

  // Link PosMatrix\MovMatrix\ViewMatrix GLSL variables to
  // _PosMatrix\_MovMatrix\_ViewMatrix javascript variables
  // Uniforms do not need to be enabled like attributes
  _PosMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "PosMatrix");
  _MovMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "MovMatrix");
  _ViewMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "ViewMatrix");

  // position GLSL variable links to _position variable
  _position = gl_ctx.getAttribLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "position");    // *******
  // color GLSL variable links to _color variable
  _color = gl_ctx.getAttribLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "color");
  // enable GLSL attributes variables
  gl_ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(_position);
  gl_ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(_color);
  // linking is over - tells WebGL context to use SHADER_PROGRAM for rendering.
  gl_ctx.useProgram(SHADER_PROGRAM);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_initBuffers () {
  // Point coordinates array of the triangle
  //   var triangleVertices = [
  //      -1, -1, 0,    // bottom left
  //       0, 0, 1,      // submit color: blue
  //       1, -1, 0,    // bottom right
  //       1, 1, 1,      // submit color: white
  //       1, 1, 0,     // top right
  //       1, 0, 0       // submit color: red
  //   ];
  var triangleVertices = [
    1,0,2,    // wierzchołek #1
    0, 0, 0,       // kolor: czarny
    1,0,0,      // wierzchołek #2
    2, 0, 0,       // kolor: czerwony
    -1,0,1,       // wierzchołek #3
    1, 1, 0,       // kolor: zółty
    0,2,0,       // wierzchołek #4
    0, 1, 0      // kolor: niebieski
  ];


  // Building Vertex Buffer Object - WebGL vertex array
  _triangleVertexBuffer = gl_ctx.createBuffer();                // *******
  gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
  gl_ctx.bufferData(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices), gl_ctx.STATIC_DRAW);


  // Triangle faces array
  // var triangleFaces = [0, 1, 2];
  var triangleFaces = [
    0, 1, 2,       // pobierz 1, 2 i 3 wierzchołek z tablicy triangleVertices
    0, 1, 3,
    1, 2, 3,
    0, 2, 3
  ];

  _triangleFacesBuffer = gl_ctx.createBuffer();                     // *******
  gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);
  gl_ctx.bufferData(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(triangleFaces), gl_ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_setMatrix () {
  _matrixProjection = MATRIX.getProjection(40, gl_canvas.width/gl_canvas.height, 1, 100);
  _matrixMovement = MATRIX.getIdentityMatrix();
  _matrixView = MATRIX.getIdentityMatrix();

  MATRIX.translateZ(_matrixView, zoomRatio);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_draw() {
  // set the color to transparent
  gl_ctx.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  // enable Depth buffer test and set depth buffer comparison function
  gl_ctx.enable(gl_ctx.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl_ctx.depthFunc(gl_ctx.LEQUAL);

  // set the clear value for the depth buffer to 1
  gl_ctx.clearDepth(1.0);

  var timeOld = 0;
  var dAngle = 0;

  var animate = function (time) {
    dAngle = rotationSpeed * (time - timeOld);

    if (X) {
      MATRIX.rotateX(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
    }
    if (Y) {
      MATRIX.rotateY(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
    }
    if (Z) {
      MATRIX.rotateZ(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
    }

    timeOld = time;

    // set the drawing area on the canvas and clear it
    gl_ctx.viewport(0.0, 0.0, gl_canvas.width, gl_canvas.height);
    gl_ctx.clear(gl_ctx.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl_ctx.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set projection matrix. _matrixProjection is not set yet.
    // It is a javascript array of 1 dimension with 16 floats
    gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_PosMatrix, false, _matrixProjection);
    gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_MovMatrix, false, _matrixMovement);
    gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_ViewMatrix, false, _matrixView);
    // drawing is here - use these points for next drawing
    // gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(variable, dimension, type, normalize, total vertex size in bytes, offset)
    gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_position, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*6, 0);
    gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*4, 0);

    gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
    gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);

    // draw the triangle
    //gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 3, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // draw cube
    gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 12, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // drawing is finished - show the render
    gl_ctx.flush();
    // redraws the scene as soon as ready
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  };

  // launch animate for the first time
  animate(timeOld);

}

var MATRIX = {
  degToRad: function(angle) {
    return (angle*Math.PI/180);
  },

  getProjection: function(angle, a, zMin, zMax) {
    var tan = Math.tan(MATRIX.degToRad(0.5*angle)),
        A=-(zMax+zMin)/(zMax-zMin),
          B=(-2*zMax*zMin)/(zMax-zMin);

    return [
      .5/tan,          0,   0,    0,
      0,   .5*a/tan,   0,    0,
      0,          0,   A,   -1,
      0,          0,   B,    0
    ]
  },

  getIdentityMatrix: function () {
    return [
      1, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1
    ];
  },

  // rotate movement matrix with angle around X axis
  rotateX: function(movMat, angle) {
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var matElem1 = movMat[1],
        matElem5 = movMat[5],
        matElem9 = movMat[9];

    movMat[1] = movMat[1]*cos - movMat[2]*sin;
    movMat[5] = movMat[5]*cos - movMat[6]*sin;
    movMat[9] = movMat[9]*cos - movMat[10]*sin;

    movMat[2] = movMat[2]*cos + matElem1*sin;
    movMat[6] = movMat[6]*cos + matElem5*sin;
    movMat[10] = movMat[10]*cos + matElem9*sin;
  },

  // rotate movement matrix with angle around Y axis
  rotateY: function(movMat, angle) {
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var matElem0 = movMat[0],
        matElem4 = movMat[4],
        matElem8 = movMat[8];

    movMat[0] = movMat[0]*cos + movMat[2]*sin;
    movMat[4] = movMat[4]*cos + movMat[6]*sin;
    movMat[8] = movMat[8]*cos + movMat[10]*sin;

    movMat[2] = movMat[2]*cos - matElem0*sin;
    movMat[6] = movMat[6]*cos - matElem4*sin;
    movMat[10] = movMat[10]*cos - matElem8*sin;
  },

  // rotate movement matrix with angle around Z axis
  rotateZ: function(movMat, angle) {
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var matElem0 = movMat[0],
        matElem4 = movMat[4],
        matElem8 = movMat[8];

    movMat[0] = movMat[0]*cos - movMat[1]*sin;
    movMat[4] = movMat[4]*cos - movMat[5]*sin;
    movMat[8] = movMat[8]*cos - movMat[9]*sin;

    movMat[1] = movMat[1]*cos + matElem0*sin;
    movMat[5] = movMat[5]*cos + matElem4*sin;
    movMat[9] = movMat[9]*cos + matElem8*sin;
  },

  // translate movement matrix by trans along Z axis
  translateZ: function (movMat, trans) {
    movMat[14] += trans;
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="rotationCheckboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateX"> Rotate X&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateY"> Rotate Y&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateZ"> Rotate Z
  </form>
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="run" onclick="runWebGL()"/>
  <br />
  <canvas id="glcanvas" width="500" height="300">Brak wsparcia dla elementu HTML canvas.</canvas>
</div>
```

Some condition before animate function call is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `runWebGL` you're creating another `requestAnimationFrame` loop. That means each time you click `run` your render loop `gl_draw` is getting executing more times per frame.

2 solutions come to mind

1. Run the loop separate from your input events

   In other words just start the loop and keep it running
   and update your rotation variables separately. Only call `runWebGL` once.

   In your case I just added a called `runWebGL` and changed all the checkboxes to call `getRotation` when clicked.

   example:

```js
var gl_canvas;
var gl_ctx;

var _triangleVertexBuffer;
var _triangleFacesBuffer;
var _position;
var _color;
var _PosMatrix;
var _MovMatrix;
var _ViewMatrix;
var _matrixProjection;
var _matrixMovement;
var _matrixView;

var rotationSpeed = 0.001;
var zoomRatio = -6;

var X, Y, Z;

function runWebGL () {
  getRotation();
  gl_canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
  gl_ctx = gl_getContext(gl_canvas);
  gl_initShaders();
  gl_initBuffers();
  gl_setMatrix();
  gl_draw();
}

function getRotation() {
  X = document.getElementById('rotateX').checked;
  Y = document.getElementById('rotateY').checked;
  Z = document.getElementById('rotateZ').checked;
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_getContext (canvas) {
  try {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
    ctx.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
    ctx.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (!ctx) {
    document.write('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.')
  }
  return ctx;
}

// ==================================================================== //

// Declare the shaders. They are pieces of code compiled by WebGL and
// executed on the graphics device. They are written in GLSL.
function gl_initShaders () {
  // position of the point - 0. is Z and 1. is W
  // PosMatrix is uniform variable - its value is constant while rendering an object
  // MovMatrix is the movement matrix of the triangle
  // gl_position -> we move position with MovMatrix before projecting it
  var vertexShader = "\n\
attribute vec3 position;\n\
uniform mat4 PosMatrix;\n\
uniform mat4 MovMatrix;\n\
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix; \n\
attribute vec3 color;\n\
varying vec3 vColor;\n\
void main(void) {\n\
gl_Position = PosMatrix * ViewMatrix * MovMatrix * vec4(position, 1.);\n\
vColor = color;\n\
}";

  // set black color
  var fragmentShader = "\n\
precision mediump float;\n\
varying vec3 vColor;\n\
void main(void) {\n\
gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);\n\
}";

  // this function is used to compile a shader
  var getShader = function(source, type, typeString) {
    var shader = gl_ctx.createShader(type);
    gl_ctx.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl_ctx.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl_ctx.getShaderParameter(shader, gl_ctx.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      alert('error in' + typeString);
      return false;
    }
    return shader;
  };

  // Compile the vertex and fragment shaders
  var shader_vertex = getShader(vertexShader, gl_ctx.VERTEX_SHADER, "VERTEX");
  var shader_fragment = getShader(fragmentShader, gl_ctx.FRAGMENT_SHADER, "FRAGMENT");


  // Create the Shader program.
  // Shader program is a combination of a vertex and fragment shaders.
  var SHADER_PROGRAM = gl_ctx.createProgram();
  gl_ctx.attachShader(SHADER_PROGRAM, shader_vertex);
  gl_ctx.attachShader(SHADER_PROGRAM, shader_fragment);


  // Linking of the shader program to the WebGL context - gl_ctx,
  // in order to match the shader variables to javascript variables
  gl_ctx.linkProgram(SHADER_PROGRAM);

  // Link PosMatrix\MovMatrix\ViewMatrix GLSL variables to
  // _PosMatrix\_MovMatrix\_ViewMatrix javascript variables
  // Uniforms do not need to be enabled like attributes
  _PosMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "PosMatrix");
  _MovMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "MovMatrix");
  _ViewMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "ViewMatrix");

  // position GLSL variable links to _position variable
  _position = gl_ctx.getAttribLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "position");    // *******
  // color GLSL variable links to _color variable
  _color = gl_ctx.getAttribLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "color");
  // enable GLSL attributes variables
  gl_ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(_position);
  gl_ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(_color);
  // linking is over - tells WebGL context to use SHADER_PROGRAM for rendering.
  gl_ctx.useProgram(SHADER_PROGRAM);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_initBuffers () {
  // Point coordinates array of the triangle
  //   var triangleVertices = [
  //      -1, -1, 0,    // bottom left
  //       0, 0, 1,      // submit color: blue
  //       1, -1, 0,    // bottom right
  //       1, 1, 1,      // submit color: white
  //       1, 1, 0,     // top right
  //       1, 0, 0       // submit color: red
  //   ];
  var triangleVertices = [
    1,0,2,    // wierzchołek #1
    0, 0, 0,       // kolor: czarny
    1,0,0,      // wierzchołek #2
    2, 0, 0,       // kolor: czerwony
    -1,0,1,       // wierzchołek #3
    1, 1, 0,       // kolor: zółty
    0,2,0,       // wierzchołek #4
    0, 1, 0      // kolor: niebieski
  ];


  // Building Vertex Buffer Object - WebGL vertex array
  _triangleVertexBuffer = gl_ctx.createBuffer();                // *******
  gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
  gl_ctx.bufferData(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices), gl_ctx.STATIC_DRAW);


  // Triangle faces array
  // var triangleFaces = [0, 1, 2];
  var triangleFaces = [
    0, 1, 2,       // pobierz 1, 2 i 3 wierzchołek z tablicy triangleVertices
    0, 1, 3,
    1, 2, 3,
    0, 2, 3
  ];

  _triangleFacesBuffer = gl_ctx.createBuffer();                     // *******
  gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);
  gl_ctx.bufferData(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(triangleFaces), gl_ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_setMatrix () {
  _matrixProjection = MATRIX.getProjection(40, gl_canvas.width/gl_canvas.height, 1, 100);
  _matrixMovement = MATRIX.getIdentityMatrix();
  _matrixView = MATRIX.getIdentityMatrix();

  MATRIX.translateZ(_matrixView, zoomRatio);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_draw() {
  // set the color to transparent
  gl_ctx.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  // enable Depth buffer test and set depth buffer comparison function
  gl_ctx.enable(gl_ctx.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl_ctx.depthFunc(gl_ctx.LEQUAL);

  // set the clear value for the depth buffer to 1
  gl_ctx.clearDepth(1.0);

  var timeOld = 0;
  var dAngle = 0;

  var animate = function (time) {
    dAngle = rotationSpeed * (time - timeOld);

    if (X) {
      MATRIX.rotateX(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
    }
    if (Y) {
      MATRIX.rotateY(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
    }
    if (Z) {
      MATRIX.rotateZ(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
    }

    timeOld = time;

    // set the drawing area on the canvas and clear it
    gl_ctx.viewport(0.0, 0.0, gl_canvas.width, gl_canvas.height);
    gl_ctx.clear(gl_ctx.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl_ctx.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set projection matrix. _matrixProjection is not set yet.
    // It is a javascript array of 1 dimension with 16 floats
    gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_PosMatrix, false, _matrixProjection);
    gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_MovMatrix, false, _matrixMovement);
    gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_ViewMatrix, false, _matrixView);
    // drawing is here - use these points for next drawing
    // gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(variable, dimension, type, normalize, total vertex size in bytes, offset)
    gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_position, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*6, 0);
    gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*4, 0);

    gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
    gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);

    // draw the triangle
    //gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 3, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // draw cube
    gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 12, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // drawing is finished - show the render
    gl_ctx.flush();
    // redraws the scene as soon as ready
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  };

  // launch animate for the first time
  animate(timeOld);

}

var MATRIX = {
  degToRad: function(angle) {
    return (angle*Math.PI/180);
  },

  getProjection: function(angle, a, zMin, zMax) {
    var tan = Math.tan(MATRIX.degToRad(0.5*angle)),
        A=-(zMax+zMin)/(zMax-zMin),
          B=(-2*zMax*zMin)/(zMax-zMin);

    return [
      .5/tan,          0,   0,    0,
      0,   .5*a/tan,   0,    0,
      0,          0,   A,   -1,
      0,          0,   B,    0
    ]
  },

  getIdentityMatrix: function () {
    return [
      1, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1
    ];
  },

  // rotate movement matrix with angle around X axis
  rotateX: function(movMat, angle) {
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var matElem1 = movMat[1],
        matElem5 = movMat[5],
        matElem9 = movMat[9];

    movMat[1] = movMat[1]*cos - movMat[2]*sin;
    movMat[5] = movMat[5]*cos - movMat[6]*sin;
    movMat[9] = movMat[9]*cos - movMat[10]*sin;

    movMat[2] = movMat[2]*cos + matElem1*sin;
    movMat[6] = movMat[6]*cos + matElem5*sin;
    movMat[10] = movMat[10]*cos + matElem9*sin;
  },

  // rotate movement matrix with angle around Y axis
  rotateY: function(movMat, angle) {
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var matElem0 = movMat[0],
        matElem4 = movMat[4],
        matElem8 = movMat[8];

    movMat[0] = movMat[0]*cos + movMat[2]*sin;
    movMat[4] = movMat[4]*cos + movMat[6]*sin;
    movMat[8] = movMat[8]*cos + movMat[10]*sin;

    movMat[2] = movMat[2]*cos - matElem0*sin;
    movMat[6] = movMat[6]*cos - matElem4*sin;
    movMat[10] = movMat[10]*cos - matElem8*sin;
  },

  // rotate movement matrix with angle around Z axis
  rotateZ: function(movMat, angle) {
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var matElem0 = movMat[0],
        matElem4 = movMat[4],
        matElem8 = movMat[8];

    movMat[0] = movMat[0]*cos - movMat[1]*sin;
    movMat[4] = movMat[4]*cos - movMat[5]*sin;
    movMat[8] = movMat[8]*cos - movMat[9]*sin;

    movMat[1] = movMat[1]*cos + matElem0*sin;
    movMat[5] = movMat[5]*cos + matElem4*sin;
    movMat[9] = movMat[9]*cos + matElem8*sin;
  },

  // translate movement matrix by trans along Z axis
  translateZ: function (movMat, trans) {
    movMat[14] += trans;
  }
};

runWebGL();
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="rotationCheckboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateX" onclick="getRotation()"> Rotate X&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateY" onclick="getRotation()"> Rotate Y&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateZ" onclick="getRotation()"> Rotate Z
  </form>
  <br />
  <canvas id="glcanvas" width="500" height="300">Brak wsparcia dla elementu HTML canvas.</canvas>
</div>
```

2. Stop the old loop before starting a new one

   You can cancel a `requestAnimationFrame` request by saving the id of the request and calling `cancelAnimationFrame`.

   In this case I added a global variable

   ```
   var requestId;
   ```

   I changed to call to `requestAnimationFrame` to save the id

   ```
   requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   ```

   And at the top of runWebGL I changed it to cancel the old request if there is one

   ```
   if (requestId) {
     window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
     requestId = undefined;
   }
   ```

   But note this example is still bad, you don't want to be creating your buffers, shaders, etc every time the user changes something. You really want solution #1

example:

```js
var gl_canvas;
var gl_ctx;

var _triangleVertexBuffer;
var _triangleFacesBuffer;
var _position;
var _color;
var _PosMatrix;
var _MovMatrix;
var _ViewMatrix;
var _matrixProjection;
var _matrixMovement;
var _matrixView;

var rotationSpeed = 0.001;
var zoomRatio = -6;
var requestId;              // ----ADDED----!

var X, Y, Z;

function runWebGL () {
  // stop old loop        
  if (requestId) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
    requestId = undefined;
  }
  
  getRotation();
  gl_canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
  gl_ctx = gl_getContext(gl_canvas);
  gl_initShaders();
  gl_initBuffers();
  gl_setMatrix();
  gl_draw();
}

function getRotation() {
  X = document.getElementById('rotateX').checked;
  Y = document.getElementById('rotateY').checked;
  Z = document.getElementById('rotateZ').checked;
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_getContext (canvas) {
  try {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
    ctx.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
    ctx.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (!ctx) {
    document.write('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.')
  }
  return ctx;
}

// ==================================================================== //

// Declare the shaders. They are pieces of code compiled by WebGL and
// executed on the graphics device. They are written in GLSL.
function gl_initShaders () {
  // position of the point - 0. is Z and 1. is W
  // PosMatrix is uniform variable - its value is constant while rendering an object
  // MovMatrix is the movement matrix of the triangle
  // gl_position -> we move position with MovMatrix before projecting it
  var vertexShader = "\n\
attribute vec3 position;\n\
uniform mat4 PosMatrix;\n\
uniform mat4 MovMatrix;\n\
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix; \n\
attribute vec3 color;\n\
varying vec3 vColor;\n\
void main(void) {\n\
gl_Position = PosMatrix * ViewMatrix * MovMatrix * vec4(position, 1.);\n\
vColor = color;\n\
}";

  // set black color
  var fragmentShader = "\n\
precision mediump float;\n\
varying vec3 vColor;\n\
void main(void) {\n\
gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);\n\
}";

  // this function is used to compile a shader
  var getShader = function(source, type, typeString) {
    var shader = gl_ctx.createShader(type);
    gl_ctx.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl_ctx.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl_ctx.getShaderParameter(shader, gl_ctx.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      alert('error in' + typeString);
      return false;
    }
    return shader;
  };

  // Compile the vertex and fragment shaders
  var shader_vertex = getShader(vertexShader, gl_ctx.VERTEX_SHADER, "VERTEX");
  var shader_fragment = getShader(fragmentShader, gl_ctx.FRAGMENT_SHADER, "FRAGMENT");


  // Create the Shader program.
  // Shader program is a combination of a vertex and fragment shaders.
  var SHADER_PROGRAM = gl_ctx.createProgram();
  gl_ctx.attachShader(SHADER_PROGRAM, shader_vertex);
  gl_ctx.attachShader(SHADER_PROGRAM, shader_fragment);


  // Linking of the shader program to the WebGL context - gl_ctx,
  // in order to match the shader variables to javascript variables
  gl_ctx.linkProgram(SHADER_PROGRAM);

  // Link PosMatrix\MovMatrix\ViewMatrix GLSL variables to
  // _PosMatrix\_MovMatrix\_ViewMatrix javascript variables
  // Uniforms do not need to be enabled like attributes
  _PosMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "PosMatrix");
  _MovMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "MovMatrix");
  _ViewMatrix = gl_ctx.getUniformLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "ViewMatrix");

  // position GLSL variable links to _position variable
  _position = gl_ctx.getAttribLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "position");    // *******
  // color GLSL variable links to _color variable
  _color = gl_ctx.getAttribLocation(SHADER_PROGRAM, "color");
  // enable GLSL attributes variables
  gl_ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(_position);
  gl_ctx.enableVertexAttribArray(_color);
  // linking is over - tells WebGL context to use SHADER_PROGRAM for rendering.
  gl_ctx.useProgram(SHADER_PROGRAM);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_initBuffers () {
  // Point coordinates array of the triangle
  //   var triangleVertices = [
  //      -1, -1, 0,    // bottom left
  //       0, 0, 1,      // submit color: blue
  //       1, -1, 0,    // bottom right
  //       1, 1, 1,      // submit color: white
  //       1, 1, 0,     // top right
  //       1, 0, 0       // submit color: red
  //   ];
  var triangleVertices = [
    1,0,2,    // wierzchołek #1
    0, 0, 0,       // kolor: czarny
    1,0,0,      // wierzchołek #2
    2, 0, 0,       // kolor: czerwony
    -1,0,1,       // wierzchołek #3
    1, 1, 0,       // kolor: zółty
    0,2,0,       // wierzchołek #4
    0, 1, 0      // kolor: niebieski
  ];


  // Building Vertex Buffer Object - WebGL vertex array
  _triangleVertexBuffer = gl_ctx.createBuffer();                // *******
  gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
  gl_ctx.bufferData(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices), gl_ctx.STATIC_DRAW);


  // Triangle faces array
  // var triangleFaces = [0, 1, 2];
  var triangleFaces = [
    0, 1, 2,       // pobierz 1, 2 i 3 wierzchołek z tablicy triangleVertices
    0, 1, 3,
    1, 2, 3,
    0, 2, 3
  ];

  _triangleFacesBuffer = gl_ctx.createBuffer();                     // *******
  gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);
  gl_ctx.bufferData(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(triangleFaces), gl_ctx.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_setMatrix () {
  _matrixProjection = MATRIX.getProjection(40, gl_canvas.width/gl_canvas.height, 1, 100);
  _matrixMovement = MATRIX.getIdentityMatrix();
  _matrixView = MATRIX.getIdentityMatrix();

  MATRIX.translateZ(_matrixView, zoomRatio);
}

// ==================================================================== //

function gl_draw() {
  // set the color to transparent
  gl_ctx.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  // enable Depth buffer test and set depth buffer comparison function
  gl_ctx.enable(gl_ctx.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl_ctx.depthFunc(gl_ctx.LEQUAL);

  // set the clear value for the depth buffer to 1
  gl_ctx.clearDepth(1.0);

  var timeOld = 0;
  var dAngle = 0;

  var animate = function (time) {
    dAngle = rotationSpeed * (time - timeOld);

    if (X) {
      MATRIX.rotateX(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
    }
    if (Y) {
      MATRIX.rotateY(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
    }
    if (Z) {
      MATRIX.rotateZ(_matrixMovement, dAngle);
    }

    timeOld = time;

    // set the drawing area on the canvas and clear it
    gl_ctx.viewport(0.0, 0.0, gl_canvas.width, gl_canvas.height);
    gl_ctx.clear(gl_ctx.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl_ctx.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set projection matrix. _matrixProjection is not set yet.
    // It is a javascript array of 1 dimension with 16 floats
    gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_PosMatrix, false, _matrixProjection);
    gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_MovMatrix, false, _matrixMovement);
    gl_ctx.uniformMatrix4fv(_ViewMatrix, false, _matrixView);
    // drawing is here - use these points for next drawing
    // gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(variable, dimension, type, normalize, total vertex size in bytes, offset)
    gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_position, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*6, 0);
    gl_ctx.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl_ctx.FLOAT, false, 4*4, 0);

    gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleVertexBuffer);
    gl_ctx.bindBuffer(gl_ctx.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _triangleFacesBuffer);

    // draw the triangle
    //gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 3, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // draw cube
    gl_ctx.drawElements(gl_ctx.TRIANGLES, 12, gl_ctx.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // drawing is finished - show the render
    gl_ctx.flush();
    // redraws the scene as soon as ready
    requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  };

  // launch animate for the first time
  animate(timeOld);

}

var MATRIX = {
  degToRad: function(angle) {
    return (angle*Math.PI/180);
  },

  getProjection: function(angle, a, zMin, zMax) {
    var tan = Math.tan(MATRIX.degToRad(0.5*angle)),
        A=-(zMax+zMin)/(zMax-zMin),
          B=(-2*zMax*zMin)/(zMax-zMin);

    return [
      .5/tan,          0,   0,    0,
      0,   .5*a/tan,   0,    0,
      0,          0,   A,   -1,
      0,          0,   B,    0
    ]
  },

  getIdentityMatrix: function () {
    return [
      1, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1
    ];
  },

  // rotate movement matrix with angle around X axis
  rotateX: function(movMat, angle) {
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var matElem1 = movMat[1],
        matElem5 = movMat[5],
        matElem9 = movMat[9];

    movMat[1] = movMat[1]*cos - movMat[2]*sin;
    movMat[5] = movMat[5]*cos - movMat[6]*sin;
    movMat[9] = movMat[9]*cos - movMat[10]*sin;

    movMat[2] = movMat[2]*cos + matElem1*sin;
    movMat[6] = movMat[6]*cos + matElem5*sin;
    movMat[10] = movMat[10]*cos + matElem9*sin;
  },

  // rotate movement matrix with angle around Y axis
  rotateY: function(movMat, angle) {
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var matElem0 = movMat[0],
        matElem4 = movMat[4],
        matElem8 = movMat[8];

    movMat[0] = movMat[0]*cos + movMat[2]*sin;
    movMat[4] = movMat[4]*cos + movMat[6]*sin;
    movMat[8] = movMat[8]*cos + movMat[10]*sin;

    movMat[2] = movMat[2]*cos - matElem0*sin;
    movMat[6] = movMat[6]*cos - matElem4*sin;
    movMat[10] = movMat[10]*cos - matElem8*sin;
  },

  // rotate movement matrix with angle around Z axis
  rotateZ: function(movMat, angle) {
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var matElem0 = movMat[0],
        matElem4 = movMat[4],
        matElem8 = movMat[8];

    movMat[0] = movMat[0]*cos - movMat[1]*sin;
    movMat[4] = movMat[4]*cos - movMat[5]*sin;
    movMat[8] = movMat[8]*cos - movMat[9]*sin;

    movMat[1] = movMat[1]*cos + matElem0*sin;
    movMat[5] = movMat[5]*cos + matElem4*sin;
    movMat[9] = movMat[9]*cos + matElem8*sin;
  },

  // translate movement matrix by trans along Z axis
  translateZ: function (movMat, trans) {
    movMat[14] += trans;
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="rotationCheckboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateX"> Rotate X&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateY"> Rotate Y&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" id="rotateZ"> Rotate Z
  </form>
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="run" onclick="runWebGL()"/>
  <br />
  <canvas id="glcanvas" width="500" height="300">Brak wsparcia dla elementu HTML canvas.</canvas>
</div>
```